# Grails json rendering as map

Tags: json, grails, gsp

I am trying to render a json response from grails controller action. Here is my code:

```
render ([message:"voila Sent Successfully!"]) as JSON
```

But in the gsp, it is rendering like:

```
['message':'Email Sent Successfully!']
```

Above text is actually a string(as its typeof in jquery ajax call gives a string in the success event handler), so how do I render it as a JSON?

I am using grails 2.4.5 and the JSON class is actually grails.converters.JSON (not grails.converters.deep.JSON)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do as

`render ([message:"voila Sent Successfully!"] as JSON )` i.e inserting `as JSON`

within parentheses.

Comment: Its ,working. But what if I assign the map to a variable like `def result=[message: "voila sent successfully!"]; render result as JSON` this should also work?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expose another answer, which avoids an issue like one that I already found in IE. Some older IE versions could try to download your JSON as a file.

Generate your JSON response from your collection/map and then render it as a string, so:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
def YourService

def yourControllerNameHere(){   
    def result = YourService.generatesYourResult(),
    resultJSON = result as JSON

    render resultJSON.toString() 
}
```

Then, in your ajax, parse this string as JSON-object using jQuery, that is:

```
$.ajax({
    url     : WEB_ROOT + 'yourUrl/yourControllerNameHere',
    type    : 'post',
    dataType: 'text',
    success : function(resultStr) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(resultStr);
        alert('this is your response type: ' + (typeof result));
        // this is your response type: object
    }
});
```